# Deserialize string to double

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "price": "0.002200"
}
```

I'd like to deserialize `price` to double, but it is a string.

How can I do?

Comment: Have you tried?  Deserializing to a `public double price { get; set; }` property already just works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bUCVL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just create a class to map the JSON:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

Then just deserialize with [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm):

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)
```

**Full Program:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    public double price { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{""price"": ""0.002200""}";

        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(root.price);
        // 0.0022
    }   
}
```

**Note:** This assumes you have the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) NuGet package installed.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create class that represents the JSON and deserialize into that class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{ \"price\": \"0.002200\" }";

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(data.Price);
    }
}

class Data
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```